# How can I speed up my login on a Windows 7 machine to a Samba domain?

Tags: windows-7, domain, samba, login

This is a problem related to Windows 7 machines using a Samba 3.5 domain. I have searched feverishly and found many solutions but none have worked.

I recently re-imaged a computer lab I'm in charge of, using clonezilla, and after applying all the images 2 computers (the 2 newest i7, 16gram, etc.) are practically unable to login to the domain. Take about 1hr+. For the admin account only a few seconds (which I feel shows it a problem with connecting to the domain...or something).

I have changed (already in the image) all the typical registry values to allow the machine:

HKLM\System\CCS\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
            DWORD  DomainCompatibilityMode = 1
            DWORD  DNSNameResolutionRequired = 0

I have also changed the group policies (solutions I found):

Start up policy processing wait time (value = 1)

Set max wait time for network if use has roaming profile (value = 1)

Changed the background to a non-solid color...to no avail.

If anyone has other solutions that they have discovered I would be for ever grateful to you!

(all the other machine take max a minute to log on to the network)